# Secured connection failed with Error code: SSL_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED_ALERT for Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-hosting

I have created a webapp and deployed it in Firebase Hosting. For some reason the website can't be loaded on some networks and clients because of an error.

We also tried accessing https://www.firebase.com/test.html and it shows the same error. Here are the details:

> **Secure Connection Failed**
>
> An error occured during a connection to www.firebase.com. Peer received a valid certificate, but access was denied. Error code: SSL_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED_ALERT
>
> - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified
> - Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem

[image: Screenshot of error]

The webapp uses AngularFire with anonymous authentication.

Comment: The test page loads fine for me. Is there some place that I can connect to to see if I can reproduce the error?

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the assistance. Their IT department said they're using Fortigate firewall for the web filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. If that firewall is filtering traffic to your Firebase Hosting app, there is little we can do about it.

Comment: @frank Sorry, to answer your question, I haven't known of a way to reproduce the error. I was initially thinking that it might be their network configuration but they told me don't have any blocking policies enforced

Comment: @Frank, I see. I'll try to let them disable the firewall and see if that works.